# Change Bitbucket's Private repo to Public repo using RESTAPI

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, bitbucket

I want to convert few of my private repositories to public repo.

```
import requests
workspace = ''
base_url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (username, password)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    "type": "repository",
    "is_private": False
}
url = f'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}'
res = session.put(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(res, res.reason)
```

But I got `<Response [400]> Bad Request`. Should I pass any other data in request body?

Comment: Is there something in `res.content` (or `res.json()`)?

Comment: res.content: {'type': 'error', 'error': {'message': 'Public repositories must allow public forks.'}}

Answer (score 1):

Try also setting `fork_policy`, i.e.

```
data = {
    "type": "repository",
    "is_private": False, 
    "fork_policy": "allow_forks"
}
```